# Limiting PID controller's output making the plant unstable and untunable

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using the PID block in Simulink and limiting the output to (+/-)5. The plant becomes unstable and untunable after putting these limits. The plant is stable and tuneable otherwise if no limits are applied. 
The output from the PID tuner goes beyond 10 when no limits are applied and I want to limit the output to 5. [image]

Comment: I consider this question off topic. I think it should be posted on https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ . It is about control engineering, not about programming. Some inputs for a question you might ask there 1) You write about a PID, but your picture shows a PI Might be intended, if so please explain it. 2) Did you try tuning the parameters of the PID to improve the situation? 3) Please show the controller output and response in a plot.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel I will repost the question in engineering stack exchange. Clarification regarding the questions you asked  1) The block for PID and PI control is the same you just need to edit some options. 2) The plant is untunable that is the reason I posted the question. 3) The step response of the plant goes to infinity.